# CakePHP REST API multipart file with json in one request

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I have problem with CakePHP request handling…
I wrote an REST API to post some data and files and use multipart/form-data when want to send data.
When sending POST request(Multipart/form-data and send data as json),need to convert $this->request->data from json string to Array:
I wrote below code to convert json data to Array in beforeFilter of my controller:

```
$parser = function ($data) {

    return json_decode($this->request->data,true);
};

$this->RequestHandler->addInputType("file", array($parser));
```

This is work fine and when I get $this->request->data in controller, JSON data successfully converted to Array,
But If I send request with file, this error happen:

Argument 1 passed to Hash::insert() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/besepari/public_html/android/lib/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php on line 401 and defined …

After research on codes,I find the problem but I couldn’t find a way to fix that.I think the error was generated because conversion of $data from json to array(in beforeFilter) happens after of this event so json string passed to Hash::insert() and make the error.need a way to convert json string of $data before of Hash::insert() execution.

**Finally I found a way to fix this,but my approach maybe isn't good solution.Because I changed the core of cakephp class.
For fix the bug, replace cakeRequest.php _processFileData() method  with this:**

```
protected function _processFileData($path, $data, $field) {
    //Fix bug of hash::insert string given(because in json multipart,$this->data is string and made a bug)
    //check if string is json,parse it and save it to $this->data
    if(!is_array($this->data)){
        $parsedData=json_decode($this->data,true);

        if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            // JSON is valid
            $this->data=$parsedData;
        }
    }

    foreach ($data as $key => $fields) {
        $newPath = $key;
        if (strlen($path) > 0) {
            $newPath = $path . '.' . $key;
        }
        if (is_array($fields)) {
            $this->_processFileData($newPath, $fields, $field);
        } else {
            $newPath .= '.' . $field;
            $this->data = Hash::insert($this->data, $newPath, $fields);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
I use cakephp 2
sorry for bad English.

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong here to being with, and that is to try sending non-form-data alongside of a `multipart/form-data` request, at least that's what it sounds like - it would help if you'd show the raw request (data) that is being sent.